# cf push -p incorrect usage

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push a package on IBM cloud

```
cf push “Backoffice” -p target/Backoffice.war
FAILED
Incorrect Usage. 
[...]
   -p   Path to app directory or to a zip file of the contents of the app directory
```

where

```
cf -v
cf version 6.33.1+c77e55743.2017-12-15
```

I don't know what to do since my call with the "-p" option is inline with the doc. I am new to cloudfoundry / IBM Cloud.
I don't have a manifest.yml  file.

Then I do  (and I get):

```
cf logs "VCBackoffice V2"
  " maximum number of connection retries reached "
```

Can you help me identifying the problem(s) ?

Comment: Not sure, but a few questions/suggestions.  Did you try w/out the quotes around your app name?  Does the file referenced actually exist?  Is the file a valid zip (try `jar tf target/Backoffice.war` and see if it can read the file)? Have you tried switching the argument order, so `cf push -p ... Backoffice`?  There's a new cf cli version, you might give that a try as well.  Also, what is your OS?  And if it's windows are you using command prompt or some other terminal?

Comment: thank you Daniel for your help. I did what you said and with further experimentation, I ended up doing a "cf login" and everything started to working fine. It seems my account was in a weird state.

Answer (score 1):

it was “Backoffice”  and not "Backoffice"  (bad quotes from a cut and paste)

Also doing a new "cf login" solved my problems